# Getting a value from InputText in another class. kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to pass a value from `InputText` as shown below. But I always get an empty string. If I write `InputText (text = 'test')`, then the word test is always transmitted and not what I enter. How to get in the `UserAcount` class the value that I enter into `InputText()`

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.metrics import dp

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('diplom.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)


class EntryMenu(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(EntryMenu, self).__init__(**kw)
        box = BoxLayout(padding=150,orientation='vertical')
        self.login = TextInput(text='', multiline=False)
        box.add_widget(self.login)
        self.password = TextInput(text='', multiline=False)
        box.add_widget(self.password)
        self.error = Label(text="")
        box.add_widget(self.error)
        box.add_widget(Button(text='Entry', on_press=self.buttonClicked))
        self.add_widget(box)

    def buttonClicked(self,btn):
        self.error.text=''
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            sql =f'''SELECT username,password
            FROM user
            WHERE username = '{self.login.text}';
            '''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results:
                if self.password.text==results[0][1]:
                    set_screen('user_acount')
                elif self.password.text!=results[0][1]:
                    self.error.text = "error password"
            else:
                self.error.text = "can not search user"



class UserAcount(Screen):
    def __init__(self,login, **kw):
        super(UserAcount, self).__init__(**kw)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.login=login
        name = Label(text=self.login)
        box.add_widget(name)
        back_button = Button(text='Exit', on_press=lambda x:
                             set_screen('menu'), size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))   
        box.add_widget(back_button)
        self.add_widget(box)


def set_screen(name_screen):
    sm.current = name_screen


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(EntryMenu(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(UserAcount(EntryMenu().login.text,name='user_acount'))

class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kvargs)

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Please tell me what I'm missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The text `InputText` does not appear in your example.

Comment: @inclement. Yes. In the 1st class `EntryMenu `self.login` I enter my login. and I want to see him in the second `UserAcount`

Comment: Can you please post here your full code?

Comment: @Yuval.R i'm update question. there is only 1 table in the database which contains id login an password

Comment: Did my code work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.
I figured it out, you pass the username only at the beginning, and therefore its not changing in the future.
This code should work:

```py
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.metrics import dp

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('diplom.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)


class EntryMenu(Screen):

    def __init__(self,myapp, **kw):
        super(EntryMenu, self).__init__(**kw)
        box = BoxLayout(padding=150,orientation='vertical')
        self.myapp = myapp
        self.login = TextInput(text='', multiline=False)
        box.add_widget(self.login)
        self.password = TextInput(text='', multiline=False)
        box.add_widget(self.password)
        self.error = Label(text="")
        box.add_widget(self.error)
        box.add_widget(Button(text='Entry', on_press=self.buttonClicked))
        self.add_widget(box)

    def buttonClicked(self,btn):
        self.error.text=''
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            sql =f'''SELECT username,password
            FROM user
            WHERE username = '{self.login.text}';
            '''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results:
                if self.password.text==results[0][1]:
                    self.myapp.set_screen('user_acount', self.login.text)
                elif self.password.text!=results[0][1]:
                    self.error.text = "error password"
            else:
                self.error.text = "can not search user"



class UserAcount(Screen):
    def __init__(self,login,myapp, **kw):
        super(UserAcount, self).__init__(**kw)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.myapp = myapp
        self.login=login
        name = Label(text=self.login)
        box.add_widget(name)
        back_button = Button(text='Exit', on_press=lambda x:
                             myapp.set_screen('menu'), size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))   
        box.add_widget(back_button)
        self.add_widget(box)








class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.username = ""
        self.userAcount = UserAcount(self.username,name='user_acount', myapp=self)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.userAcount)
        self.entryMenu = EntryMenu(name='menu', myapp=self)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.entryMenu)
        self.set_screen("menu")

    def build(self):
        return self.sm

    def set_screen(self, name_screen, username=None):
        if username != None and name_screen == "user_acount":
            self.username = username
            self.sm.remove_widget(self.userAcount)
            self.userAcount = UserAcount(self.username,name='user_acount', myapp=self)
            self.userAcount.login = self.username
            self.sm.add_widget(self.userAcount)
            
        self.sm.current = name_screen


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: it won't change in the future, yes. The code works from a piece. When changing a user, the login does not change.

Comment: You are correct, I have updated the code, does it works now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty
 will be able to give early reward for this answer in 20 hours

Comment: the same as I put. Gave an award for this answer. Thanks again!